# Is there a way to replace a column in a SELECT * query when the two columns have the same name because of an AS?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT *, de_display_name AS display_name FROM something
```

When I run this, two columns called `display_name` are shown, the original (from the `*`) and the replacement of `de_display_name`.

Is there a way to just have a single `display_name` column?

Comment: No.  MySQL requires that you explicitly list the columns in the result set, unless you resort to dynamic SQL.

Comment: Why not changes `de_display_name AS display_name` to `de_display_name AS display_name_2`?

Comment: No, `*` always includes all the columns of the table. The SQL Standard does not have column selectors that could allow you to remove specific columns fron an `*` either. I've only seen these selectors in Sequelize, but that's not standard.

Comment: Never use `SELECT *`